# Unable to add prebuilt apk to AOSP A13 build

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to add a prebuilt apk to an A13 AOSP build but the apk is never copied to the out directory of the build. Not error thrown during build process but the apk is not copied

I have tried the following:
Created the directory device/company/product/test_app.
Copied my apk and Android.bp file under the "test_app" directory.
Triggered a full AOSP build using make.

Contents of the Android.bp file:

android_app_import {

```
name: "test_app",

apk: "test_app.apk",

presigned: true,

privileged: true,
```

}

I know the build process is picking up the Android.bp file because if I put some garbage on it, the build fails at the point.

Update: Another point is that I ran mm inside the "device///test_app" directory and the test_app.apk file was copied to the out directory. This tells me that the Android.bp file is setup correctly.

Update2:I have tried doing a clean build but issue is still seen.

Comment: Did you add your module test_app to the PRODUCT_PACKAGES variable for the makefile for your lunch target?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've set up the Android.bp file correctly, and if the build process isn't throwing any errors, it's likely that the APK isn't being copied due to some other issue. Here are a few things you can check:

1. Ensure that the "test_app.apk" file is present in the same directory as your Android.bp file.
2. Verify that the path you provided for the "apk" attribute in Android.bp is relative to the location of the Android.bp file. Double-check for any typos in the filename or case sensitivity issues.
3. Make sure the AOSP build system is aware of your device configuration and the "test_app" module. Check that the "device///test_app" directory is properly configured for your specific device and that you've added it to the relevant device configuration files.
4. Check if there are any specific build rules or dependencies required for your "test_app" module that might be missing or misconfigured.
5. Ensure that your AOSP build environment is up-to-date, and there are no conflicting changes in your local build setup.
6. You can also try cleaning the build using `make clean` and then triggering a fresh build to see if that resolves the issue.

If none of these steps resolve the problem, you may need to dig deeper into the AOSP build logs to identify any specific issues or dependencies that might be causing the APK not to be copied to the output directory.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Ensure that your AOSP build environment is up-to-date"?